# How can I increase the computation limit in Devnet?

Tags: cluster, network

Currently `mainet` have a computation limit of 1.2m compute units limit, while `devnet` has 200k compute units limit.

Is there a way to increase the computation limit in `devnet` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Compute budget for a single transaction can be changed by adding an instruction call to the Compute Budget Program. By default the compute budget is set the product of 200k compute units * number of instructions.

Note: To change the compute budget for a transaction, you must make the one of the first three instructions of the transaction the instruction that sets the budget.

```
import {
  ComputeBudgetProgram,
} from "@solana/web3.js";


const additionalComputeBudgetInstruction = ComputeBudgetProgram.requestUnits({
    units: 400000, // max of 1.4m
    additionalFee: 0,
});
```

Complete guide in the [cookbook](https://solanacookbook.com/references/basic-transactions.html#how-to-change-compute-budget-for-a-transaction)