# What is the main function of setComputeUnitLimit? Can the instruction 1232 limit be expanded?

Tags: transactions, instructions

The transaction instruction length limit is 1232, can it be modified through setComputeUnitLimit? In what scenario is setComputeUnitLimit used?

Answer (score 3):

As of right now, the the 1232 byte length is a hard limit that cannot be adjusted. However, this limit may be expanded in the near future.

Comment: It's doubtful that this limit will increase in the near future. This size limit is a ipv6 packet size limitation. However, there could be work done to make tx serialization more efficient (like using account look-up tables)

Answer (score 1):

A transaction may set the maximum number of compute units it is allowed to consume and the compute unit price by including a SetComputeUnitLimit and a SetComputeUnitPrice Compute budget instructions respectively.

If no SetComputeUnitLimit is provided the limit will be calculated as the product of the number of instructions in the transaction (excluding the Compute budget instructions) and the default per-instruction units, which is currently 200k.

Here is an example of increasing computation limit in Devnet using javascript [How can I increase the computation limit in Devnet?](https://solana.stackexchange.com/questions/1794/how-can-i-increase-the-computation-limit-in-devnet)

---

https://docs.solana.com/developing/programming-model/runtime#prioritization-fees